# How to create a Result Set

Tags: phalcon

I need to create a result set in phalcon and use it as it was an array.

Im trying to find an example or more info on the documentation but it seems it's not possible.

Comment: You might need to be a little more specific in describing what you need to know. It's considered good habit to describe your problem in more detail and to include any efforts that you have already made. The information [here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/db.html) doesn't help you?

Answer (score 2):

On the [API](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Resultset_Simple.html) you can see the contructor params, this one is for a `Resultset/Simple`

`public function __construct($columnMap, $model, $result, \Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface $cache=null, $keepSnapshots=null){ }`

an example:

`$robot = new Robot();
$robots = new Resultset(null, $robot, $robot->getReadConnection()->query($sql, $params));`

You must take in consideration that the Resultset is not a collection, it is a traversable pointer to the database conecction. There is a post where the team will consider to add more "collection" functionalities to the object: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/10580